# Java Enum Deserialization without class model getting null value

Tags: java, java-8, enums, enumeration, java-9

I have an Enum class like below. I need to de serialize a Json string(With Key Value pair Format) to the below Enum Object very efficiently in Java8 or above.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    RED("Apple","Fruit"),
    GREEN("Hulk", "Monster");

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private final String name;
    private final String type;

    @JsonCreator
    public static TestEnum fromValue(String v) {
        System.out.println("fromValue() -->  : " + v);
        for (TestEnum myEnum : values()) {
            if (myEnum.name.equals(v)) {
                return myEnum;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid string value passed: " + v);
    }
}
```

When I am passing the input value with "Key:Value" format, the @JsonCreator Method is receiving null value(fromValue() -->  : null). But when I pass input with only Value (EX : ""Apple""). @JsonCreator method is getting the value properly. What did I miss here? Please any help. Thanks in Advance.

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        //String input = "\"Apple\"";
        String input = "{\n  \"scanType\": \"Auto-LightWeight\"\n}";
        System.out.println("Input is : " + input);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println("Enum : " + mapper.readValue(input, TestEnum.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it , I need to mention the key name using @JsonProperty in the parameter Field of FromValue()

```
@JsonCreator
    public static TestEnum fromValue(@JsonProperty(value = "name", required = true) String v) {
..
...
}
```